# In a MovementComponent, where should I initialize member variables?

Tags: c++, physics, movement, unreal-4

I have a `MovementComponent` derived from `CharacterMovementComponent`

`MovementComponent`, attached to a `Character`, needs a reference to `GrappleComponent`, stored on the `Character`.

Where do I perform the `GetComponentByClass` call to obtain this reference to the `GrappleComponent`?

If this is the constructor, could I please have some information on how to override the constructor?

Comment: I think the safest would be to perform it in begin play, however it  should also be ok in ConstructionScript C++ equivalent (Not constructor!) virtual void OnConstruction(const FTransform& Transform) OVERRIDE;

Comment: @ColdSteel Does the CharacterMovementComponent have a beginPlay I can override? Or am I simply overlooking the inheritance from UObject that provides this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you want to initialize default values of your member variables in the Constructor itself it will be the faster way since UE4 uses CDO, however if you want to get a reference/pointer to another component you shall do it in `virtual void BeginPlay()` because at the time your constructor is called the other component/actor/whatever object may not yet be initialized.

In BeginPlay you should normally have everything initialized (but, not began play yet).

Example:

In my constructor I am initializing the most common primitives:

```
UCNWCharacterMovementComponent::UCNWCharacterMovementComponent() //My Custom CMC constructor 
{
    m_SmoothSpeed = 5.0f;
    m_bUsesApexCloth = false;
    b_astaring = false;
    bAutoRegisterUpdatedComponent = false;

    OldVelocity = FVector::ZeroVector;

    m_rotationSpeed = 4.0f;
    m_bVisualizeMovement = true;
    m_bIsMoving = false;
```

}

In my BeginPlay I am getting my pointers/references to components I am about to use:

```
void UCNWCharacterMovementComponent::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    SetComponentTickEnabled(false);

    //Disable Automatic Rotation!
    bOrientRotationToMovement = false;

    bIgnoreClientMovementErrorChecksAndCorrection = false;
    m_SkipFloorChecks = true;

    m_ownerRef = (ACBaseUnitCharacter*)CharacterOwner;
    if (m_ownerRef.IsValid())
    {
        m_nwAIControllerRef = Cast<ANWAIController>(m_ownerRef->Controller);
        m_desiredRotation = m_ownerRef->GetActorRotation();
    }
    TArray<AActor *> grid;
    UGameplayStatics::GetAllActorsOfClass(this, ANavigationGridActor::StaticClass(), grid);
    if(grid.Num() > 0)
    {
        m_navGridActor = (ANavigationGridActor*)grid[0];
    }

    TArray<AActor *> ObstacleProvider;
    UGameplayStatics::GetAllActorsOfClass(this, ARVO2ObstacleProvider::StaticClass(), ObstacleProvider);
    if (ObstacleProvider.Num() > 0)
    {
        m_obstacleProvider = (ARVO2ObstacleProvider*)ObstacleProvider[0];
    }

    m_unitRadius = m_ownerRef->GetCapsuleComponent()->GetScaledCapsuleRadius();
    m_unitRadiusSQ = m_unitRadius * m_unitRadius;

    MaxSimulationIterations = 100;
    m_currentSimulatedPosition = GetActorLocation();
}
```

Begin play will always be executed after the constructor:
As you can see i do have some primetives set in `BegnPlay` as well
but that's only because I want to be sure that they will be in these values and noone will mess them up normally you don't want the primitives to be set (unless they are dependent on actors/components (run-time created stuff)).

Comment: You should open a new question, and  post your code.